# Custom UITableViewCell with an optional image

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableView` cell that has a `UIImageView` sized to the width of the cell at the top, and a `UILabel` underneath it.

A `UITableViewCell` has an `imageView` property. If the image view's image is set, then it pushes the cell `textLabel` to the right, to accomodate the image. I would like to do something similar with my table view cell (except that my label would be pushed down).

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do it is to subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `layoutSubviews` method.

Here a simple example.

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@implementation CustomCell

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];

   // grab bound for contentView
   CGRect contentViewBound = self.contentView.bounds;

   if(self.imageView.image) {
      // do stuff here, for example put the image right...
      CGRect imageViewFrame = self.imageView.frame;
      // change x position
      imageViewFrame.postion.x = contentViewBound.size.width - imageViewFrame.size.width;
      // assign the new frame
      self.imageView.frame = imageViewFrame;
   }

   else {
      // do stuff here
   }
}
```

In particular inside this method you can position the components for your cell depending on `image`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I was just trying out something along this line, it's good to get some reassurance that I'm on the right path. Thanks!