# Primer for "enhanced" iOS table cells?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitableview

I am relatively new to Objective C/iOS development so I realize that this may seem like a basic question: For iOS 5+, I'm looking for a primer on how to create a tableview that has cells with a variety of data. For example, in my data array I might have data like:

1. Restaurant Name (basic string)
2. Restaurant Logo (string name of an image file)
3. Restaurant Rating (an integer)

In a single cell, I want to display the logo of the restaurant, then the name, and then show a number of stars based on the rating integer (ie a "4" would display a single star image 4 times).

I can't tell if I can do this with the standard table cell or if I need to create a custom table cell object.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good place to start.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

One point they make is that if you subclass `UITableViewCell` then you have done something wrong.  Instead, read it as most of the time customizing the standard `UITableViewCell` is sufficient.

For spectacular customization then deriving a class from `UITableViewCell` is fine.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me about 90% of what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give you some suggestions on how to reach your goal based on my experience.

I think you can use both a default cell or a custom one.

In the first case, you have can use a simple cell (`UITableViewCell`) with a default style.
The properties you can use are: `imageView` for the logo, `textLabel` for the name and `accessoryView` for the rating.
Take a look to [A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7) for info about table cell structure.
If you have to maintain a specific order for your cell content you need to create a custom cell that extends `UITableViewCell` and override `layoutSubviews` methods. I've already answered a question in this stackoverflow topic [custom-uitableviewcell-with-an-optional-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720684/custom-uitableviewcell-with-an-optional-image/).

In the second case you can use a custom xib or a completely fresh cell and do the stuff there. Out of there you can find lot of guides to do that. Here fews:

1. The one that @bbarnhart has written
2. [custom-uitableviewcell](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/)
3. [creating-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-ios-4](http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/07/16/creating-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-ios-4/) (suggested)

P.S. For creating a rate view I suggest to take a look at [how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Apple doc on cells, it was very helpful for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a standard table view cell with an image and subtitle. The main text label is the restauraunt name, the image view holds your logo, and the subtitle can be made of the appropriate number of unicode star characters (for example, `@"\u2605"`).